# Spring Boot 3 Micrometer Tracing Example

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer

If I understand the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70965480/springboot-3-0-0-m1-springcloud-2022-0-0-m1-error-dependency-version-for-o) correctly, Spring Cloud Sleuth will be replaced by Micormeter Tracing with Spring Boot 3. My experiments with Spring Boot 3 milestone 3 to implement tracing have failed so far. Is there an example project somewhere that I can use to guide me.

BTW: Here are my experiments https://github.com/stse/spring-boot-otel. I try to use micrometer tracing and open telemetry to push traces to new relic via Otlp and Grpc.

Comment: I am the author of the related question and upvoted this one

Answer (score 7):

This blogpost from Spring Team will help to set it up: https://spring.io/blog/2022/10/12/observability-with-spring-boot-3

Also, I have come up with a sample Spring Boot 3 + Micrometer project here - https://github.com/kishorek/java/tree/main/spring-observability-demo.

I am using Zipkin Brave as distributed tracing implementation. I have created a python service consumed by the Spring boot service. Please refer to the README.

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot `v3.2` it has become much easier to implement tracing leveraging micrometer. you just need to add the following dependency :

```
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'
```

rest will be taken care of by the framework. look at the following example I created.

https://github.com/5aab/sb3-tracing/blob/main/build.gradle

**Please note** that there seems to be a bug in the Spring reactive stack at the time of writing this article and hence traces are not getting printed out of the box with the above dependency. please see here for more details

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/3184

Comment: If anyone wonder why it's not working after adding this dependency then don't forget to add actuator dependency as well. For me it was the issue after adding the micrometer dependency. 

implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"

Answer (score 0):

I also refered to the [post](https://spring.io/blog/2022/10/12/observability-with-spring-boot-3) on Spring Blog too,

then I made a little improvement on integrating with Spring Aspect to log

1. set the logger with the class name correctly (instead of the `MyHandler` )
2. log the method args by using the `ProceedingJoinPoint`

feel free to take a look on my [article](https://medium.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-3-observability-monitor-application-on-the-method-level-8057abec5926) and the [Pull request](https://github.com/NoahHsu/event-sourcing-order-poc/pull/43) to do so on my side project.

Answer (score -2):

Here are the links to different guides for **Spring Boot 3 & Micrometer Tracing Integration**, one can follow depending on the Tech Stack:

1. [OpenTelemetry + Jaeger](https://amithkumarg.medium.com/distributed-tracing-with-spring-boot-micrometer-opentelemetry-and-jaeger-fafd5c0bd282)
2. [gRPC + OpenTelemetry + Jaeger](https://medium.com/@amithkumarg/spring-boot-3x-grpc-app-enable-distributed-tracing-using-micrometer-opentelemetry-and-jaeger-cb1f581d655d)
3. [Brave + Zipkin](https://medium.com/@amithkumarg/distributed-tracing-for-spring-boot-3x-app-using-micrometer-brave-and-zipkin-a43fc107bff4)
4. [gRPC + Brave + Zipkin](https://medium.com/@amithkumarg/distributed-tracing-for-spring-boot-3x-grpc-app-using-micrometer-brave-and-zipkin-e49583219485)
5. [OpenTelemetry + Zipkin](https://medium.com/@amithkumarg/distributed-tracing-for-spring-boot-3x-app-using-micrometer-opentelemetry-and-zipkin-875c40a78405)
6. [gRPC + OpenTelemetry + Zipkin](https://medium.com/@amithkumarg/distributed-tracing-for-spring-boot-3x-app-using-micrometer-opentelemetry-and-zipkin-875c40a78405#e90a)

And common to all, enabling Micrometer Tracing for:

- [@Async](https://amithkumarg.medium.com/micrometer-tracing-in-spring-boot-context-propagation-for-async-scheduled-newspan-b80f4f4b2c9f#7eef)
- [@Scheduled](https://amithkumarg.medium.com/micrometer-tracing-in-spring-boot-context-propagation-for-async-scheduled-newspan-b80f4f4b2c9f#8df3)
- [Span Annotations](https://amithkumarg.medium.com/micrometer-tracing-in-spring-boot-context-propagation-for-async-scheduled-newspan-b80f4f4b2c9f#163e):
  `@NewSpan, @ContinueSpan, @SpanTag`
- [ForkJoinPool](https://amithkumarg.medium.com/distributed-tracing-spring-boot-micrometer-and-forkjoinpool-3dc8f06885f5)

**NOTE:**

These medium blog(s) are behind a paywall. If you are not already a member, no need to (pay) signup, you can directly find the source codes here for different tracing tech stack:

https://github.com/amithkumarg/springboot-micrometer-otel-zipkin
https://github.com/amithkumarg/springboot-micrometer-brave-zipkin
https://github.com/amithkumarg/springboot-otel-micrometer-jaeger

Comment: This appears to be promoting your blog with the actual information behind a paywall.  As such, this isn't a useful answer.

Comment: @MattJ - It wasn't only to promote my blogs but also to provide a consolidated indexing to all the blogs one to chose from based on their tech stack. Its still a valid answer for the audience who has medium accounts. But you have a point about the paywall. So now, I have also added the github links to the sample projects as asked by the OP which one can refer for self training without necessarily going through medium platform. Hope, these repos helps you find what you are looking for.

Comment: No access to articles. 
Async
Scheduled